# Python pandas: convert a column to a string?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some columns:

```
0                                            ['XS', '2X']
1                                      ['A2', '2X', '8W']
2                                                  ['2X']
3                    ['A2', 'FR', 'XS', '8W', '8E', '2X']
4                    ['A5', 'FR', 'XS', 'QF', '2X', '23']
5                                      ['XS', '2X', 'MF']
6                                                    None
```

that I am trying to iterate over. It I loop over the column and get the type:

```
for item in data1['business_types']:
    print(type(item))
```

It shows that the types are of type str

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'NoneType'>
```

I would like to convert the objects in this column to a list object that I can iterate over.

Comment: You can use the function DataFrame.astype(str)

Comment: Maybe l = data1['business_types'].tolist() and then l = [ast.literal_eval(i) for i in l]

Comment: I think your title should be convert column of strings to column of lists of strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `ast.literal_eval` with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace `None` to `[]`:

```
data1['business_types'] = data1['business_types'].fillna('[]').apply(ast.literal_eval)
print (data1)
             business_types
0                  [XS, 2X]
1              [A2, 2X, 8W]
2                      [2X]
3  [A2, FR, XS, 8W, 8E, 2X]
4  [A5, FR, XS, QF, 2X, 23]
5              [XS, 2X, MF]
6                        []
```

If need `None` (`NaN`s):

```
def f(x):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(x)
    except ValueError:
        return x

import ast

data1['business_types'] = data1['business_types'].apply(f)
print (data1)
             business_types
0                  [XS, 2X]
1              [A2, 2X, 8W]
2                      [2X]
3  [A2, FR, XS, 8W, 8E, 2X]
4  [A5, FR, XS, QF, 2X, 23]
5              [XS, 2X, MF]
6                       NaN

for item in data1['business_types']:
    print(type(item))

<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'float'>
```

Comment: What version are you using? I actually had tried that and I get `ValueError: malformed node or string: None` under 0.20.2. I actually just updated from 0.19.2 and it's broke some of my code...

Comment: I use pandas `0.20.1`, but if bad data, then it can failed :(

Comment: i see problem, get my some time

Comment: Is possible replace `None` to empty string?

Comment: This worked, I had tried a solution with ast.literal_eval function however, the trick with filling the Nonetypes with [] was clever and worked. Thanks.

Comment: Supeeer. First I have problem `None` in my sample was `string`, so get erorr. Good luck and thank you.